# How to write byte of array to PDF/A-3 and attachment in C# / Vb.net [Close]

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, system.io.file, pdfa

I want to convert PDF to PDF/a-3 as byte[] and file attachment .

I've tried [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) from these example [PDF/AConvert.NET](https://github.com/ETDA/PdfAConverter.net)

But the problem is i can't use `File.WriteAllBytes()` on my scenario because i have to avoid to write a File on directory.

In another way i have pdfData as byte Array how can i write it to pdf/a-3

it would be great if there are other solution,
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a physical file using a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream); you can use a [`MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream) to write directly to memory, and then use that as your stream.

`FileStream` and `MemoryStream` are both derived from [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream).